# Access directive state and populate ngFor

Tags: angular2-directives

I have settings in a backend exposed via a service.  It's very common to wire up widgets over and over to settings, so I created a directive to allow setting the unique name of the setting to attach a widget to:

`<dropdown appSetting="uniqueName">`

I've got the two way binding working.

Now in settings that represent groups there's an enum that defines the options.  I'd like to use the bound setting to populate the `ngFor` for the children:

```
<dropdown appSetting="uniqueName" #selector>
  <option *ngFor="let option of selector.setting.options">
```

Obviously that doesn't work.  I can't access directive state.  Most of the things I tried ended up with an undefined `ngForOf` or the wonderful `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.  Is there a clean way to leverage the existing directive to populate the children?

(I've tried a custom `*appFor`, but couldn't quite get it working)

Comment: It looks likes you've asked a question referring to Angular (2+), but you have tagged this question for AngularJS (1.x).

Answer (score 0):

Better Answer:

Directives have an export ability that allows them to be referenced.  Just needed to add:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appSetting]',
  exportAs: 'appSetting'
})
```

Then access as:

```
  <dropdown
        appSetting="uniqueName" #varId="appSetting"
        [(ngModel)]="varId.settingValue">
        <option *ngFor="let option of varId.options" [value]="option">{{ option }}</option>
  </dropdown>
```

---

Original Answer

---

A simple wrapper component did the job giving access to the state of a setting for any object in the template:

```
<setting-group #setting
  [uniqueName]="foo">
  <dropdown
    [(ngModel)]="setting.settingValue">
    <option *ngFor="let option of setting.options">{{ option }}</option>
  </dropdown>
</setting-group>
```

If there's a way to avoid the one-off wrapper for this, please let me know.